# wordpress - how to use javascript variable in php file

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I am a wordpress beginner.

In `Theme Editor`, I have a js file below:

```
const isMenuOpen = false;

function toggleMenu() {
    alert("toggle");
    isMobileMenuOpen = !isMobileMenuOpen;

}
```

In my php file,

```
<button onclick="toggleMenu()">
  toggle
</button>
<div>My Menu</div> // how can I make it show when isMenuOpen is true?
```

I am wondering how can I use the variable `isMenuOpen` in my php file?

Answer (score 1):

You can't
but,
When you toggle it add a class name to the body and then make it by CSS

also, you can't modify const element

JS

```
function toggleMenu() {
   document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].toggle("menu-is-open")
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="menu" > Menu </div>
```

CSS:

```
body:not(.menu-is-open) .menu{ display:none }
```